# Annoying little dot appears with an unordered list with display: inline

Tags: html, css

I stacked on the following problem. I have got an unordered list with the social icons and kind of a little dot appears on the right down corner of the icons when I change the `display` to `inline`.

HTML

```
<div class="iconos">
  <ul class="contacto">
    <li>
      <a href="mailto:xxxxxx.com" class="socialicon">
        <img src="images/mail.png" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx" class="socialicon">
        <img src="images/facebook.png" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxx" class="socialicon">
        <img src="images/twitter.png" width="50" height="50">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.contacto {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.contacto li {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That dot is an underline from `<a>` element. You can hide with this:

```
.contacto li a {
    text-decoration: none;    
}
```